# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer PEAR PHP - Generating with junk characters

Tags: php, yii, pear

I am trying simple code for excel generation. but its coming with the below output. Any help.

```
                // Creating a workbook
                $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

                // sending HTTP headers
                $workbook->send('test.xls');

                // Creating a worksheet
                $worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('My first worksheet');

                // The actual data
                $worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Name');
                $worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Age');

                // my database res

                // Let's send the file
                $workbook->close();
```

> ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ  þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 
>          þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   l   ÉBäMy
>   first
>   worksheet=¼%r8X"1ÈÿArial1ÈÿArial1ÈÿArial1ÈÿArial1ÈÿArial1ÈArialàõÿ
>   À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ
>   À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À à À à À
>   “€ÿ’â8ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ€€€€€€€€€ÀÀÀ€€€™™ÿ™3fÿÿÌÌÿÿffÿ€€fÌÌÌÿ€ÿÿÿÿÿÿ€€€€€ÿÌÿÌÿÿÌÿÌÿÿ™™Ìÿÿ™ÌÌ™ÿÿÌ™3fÿ3ÌÌ™ÌÿÌÿ™ÿfff™–––3f3™f333™3™3f33™333…?My
>   first worksheet
>     l   É*+€‚Áƒ„&è?'è?(ð?)ð?¡"dXXà?à?
>   NameAge>       ¶       Root
>   Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÀF€*ÃûdÍ€*ÃûdÍ@Book 
>   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ  ÀF9þÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Answer (score 0):

Your script is echoing data before the file itself, eg the string "OUPUT" at the beginning and "Excel created" at the end

You must not echo **any** additional output when creating the file to send to the browser, otherwise it gets included in the file.

What you consider junk characters is the actual BIFF Excel file content. What Excel considers valid content is being corrupted by your junk outputs.

Of course, you also need to send the necessary headers to tell the browser that the content you're sending it is an Excel file and not the HTML that it expects

Comment: Even though i deleted those echo statements i get the same issue.

Comment: Check to see if you're exchoing anything else.... and set the headers. Without headers telling the browser that this is an Excel file, it will render it in the browser as a binary stream

Comment: I added these headers still having the same problem. Please help me in getting this issues solve.                                                                            `header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));`

Comment: Instead of writing your headers yourself, try using `Yii::app()->request->sendFile` It works quite nicely ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
```

before the download code.